# Fragment code of image Upload is not working

Tags: android

Generally I had code for Image picker and I had following code in a Fragment but whenever I run the data is sent to server but image is not sent.

```
    private void startingCameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("====onActivityResult");
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {


            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
                    null);
            Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            filepath = cursor.getString(column_index);

            System.out.println("file path is :----" + filepath);
            System.out.println("file selectedImageUri :----" + selectedImageUri);

            imageview_pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(selectedImageUri).fit().into(imageview_pic);

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
            // thumbnail.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail,1024,768,true);

            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            imageview_pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            System.out.println("===Image Path : " + destination);
            System.out.println("===thumbnail : " + thumbnail);
            filepath = String.valueOf(destination);
            Log.d("Image path",filepath);
            imageview_pic.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        } else {

        }

    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class postadd extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
    {

        String title = ettitle.getText().toString();
        String name = etname.getText().toString();
        String city = etcity.getText().toString();
        String district = text.getText().toString();
        String taluka = text1.getText().toString();
        String contact = etcontact.getText().toString();
        String price = etprice.getText().toString() + " / " + item;
        String details = etdetails.getText().toString();
       // String img=selectedImageUri.getPath().toString();


        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        private static final String LOGIN_URL = "Image Upload URL";

        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "result";


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("file_upload",filepath);
                map.put("add_title", title);
                map.put("cat", cat_id);
                map.put("sub_cat", finalsubcatid);
                map.put("add_price", price);
                map.put("add_description", details);
                map.put("add_name", name);
                map.put("add_phone", contact);
                map.put("add_city", city);
                map.put("add_district", district);
                map.put("add_taluka", taluka);

                Log.d("request", "starting");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", map);

                if (json != null) {
                    Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                    return json;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            if (pd != null && pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }

            if (json != null) {
               /* Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, json.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
*/
                try {
                    //  result = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    result = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(result.equals("true"))
            {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Add Posted Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Post  Not Done...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
```

The above code is used in PostAddFragment from where Camera intent is call to click and when post add button is hit it upload image to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send image like this, you may need to send it as an Multipart Entity or you can send it as a String also using Base64 encoding which can be hectic.

```
    String path = Utils.getPath(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    byte[] imageBytes = getBytesFromBitmap(bitmap);
    final String image = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

image will be your string of image

```
           map.put("image ", image );
```

and on server side you have to get it as s String and decode it using Base64 decoder